# Character Arrays versus Character Pointers regarding size

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

Quote from an article I read:

*...Consider the following two variables:

```
char s6[ ] = "hello", *s7 = "hello";
```

`s6` allocates space for exactly 6 bytes; `s7` allocates space for 10 ( typically ) - 6 for the characters plus another 4 for the pointer variable.*

Curious about to who holds the address of `s6` (of the first char in the array)? And how does `s6` 'save' the 4 bytes for the pointer?

Comment: Could you please add the source reference?

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) for `s6`.

Comment: https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/C_Programming/CharacterStrings.html

Comment: nope... `s6` allocates 6 bytes... but `s7` allocates 6 bytes for the pointed string, and `sizeof char *` more, for the pointer variable.  The address of `s6` is handled by the compiler as it should do with any other constant (like `M_PI` or `M_E`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put it simply, it's not stored anywhere in your program. Only the compiler keeps track of it.

Under the hood:

- `s6` means "address XXXXXXXX: a block of six bytes, holding the values `'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0`"
- `s7` means "address YYYYYYYY: a block of four bytes, holding the values `ZZ, ZZ, ZZ, ZZ`"
- `*s7` means "address ZZZZZZZZ: a block of one byte, holding the value `'H'`"

The *program* doesn't actually have to store the value XXXXXXXX anywhere; the *compiler* just inserts the value XXXXXXXX anywhere that you use `s6`.

Similarly, the program doesn't have to store YYYYYYYY anywhere, but it *does* store ZZZZZZZZ, because you specifically said so (you said to assign the value ZZZZZZZZ to the variable `s7`).

If you want to store XXXXXXXX somewhere, though, you can easily do so:

```
char my_pointer* = &s6;
```

Now `my_pointer` means "address WWWWWWWW: a block of four bytes, holding the values `XX, XX, XX, XX`".

P.S. This is assuming you're on a system with four-byte pointers; nowadays, it's more likely that a pointer is eight bytes, or 64 bits.

Comment: @schantischul In some ways, yes! You can't, for example, make `s6` point to something new; it's fixed and immutable. But you could make `s7` point to a different string, changing the value stored in it (replacing `ZZZZZZZZ` with something else, while `YYYYYYYY` remains fixed).

Comment: (Though in other respects, no; you can't take the address of a `#define` macro, for example.)

Comment: _"it does store ZZZZZZZZ, because you specifically said so"_ -- Note that the compiler only really has to do this if `s7` has external linkage, i.e. if it is defined outside of a function without the `static` keyword. Otherwise, an optimizing compiler will likely just optimize it away, and both versions will result in [essentially the same code](https://godbolt.org/z/wQmJr_).

Answer (score 3):

> *s6 allocates space for exactly 6 bytes; s7 allocates space for 10 ( typically ) - 6 for the characters plus another 4 for the pointer variable.*

No, that's not correct.

`s6` has space for exactly 6 bytes, `s7` has space (size) of that of a pointer (4 or 8 bytes usually, depending on your architecture) and it points to the string used to initialize it.

In other words,

- size of `s6` is `sizeof ("hello")`.
- size of `s7` is `sizeof (s7)`, i.e, `sizeof (char *)`

You can execute the below program to check the sizes:

```
#include  <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s6[ ] = "hello", *s7 = "hello";

    printf("s6 = %zu\n", sizeof (s6));
    printf("s7 = %zu\n", sizeof (s7));

    return 0;
}
```

On my system, they yield:

> s6 = 6          // sizeof ("hello"), or , sizeof (char [6])
>
> s7 = 8          // sizeof (char *)

Comment: Might want to point out that `s7` is usable because string literals (like `"hello"`) have static storage duration.  This means that `s7` always points at the first character, and the string is guaranteed to exist.

Comment: can you change it?

Comment: @schantischul can you change what?

Comment: the value/address of s6/s7?

Comment: @schantischul `s6` is an array, you can change the contents. `s7` is a pointer, you can point it to some other string or memory location, like `s7 = "there";`, but you cannot change the address of either `s6` or `s7` at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

> Curious about to who holds the address of s6 (of the first char in the
>   array)? And how does s6 'save' the 4 bytes for the pointer?

The compiler/ linker hold this address. It is treated as a constant, because it can't be modified at run time. I hope this helps.